# Prove the differentiability of the following function two variables on $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Prove the differentiability of the following  function two variables at $(0,0)$

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1, & \mbox{if } x \neq 0, \:  \mbox{and} \: y \neq 0 \\ 2, & \mbox{if } x = 0, \:  \mbox{and} \: y = 0\end{cases}$$

My intuition tells me the following function is not differentiable at $(0,0)$. So my approach to this, is showing this function is not continuous at $(0,0)$. So I consider the sequence $\lbrace (\frac{1}{n} , \frac{1}{n})\rbrace_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which converges to $(0,0)$ as $n$ aproaches to infinity. But $\lbrace f(\frac{1}{n} , \frac{1}{n})\rbrace_{n \in \mathbb{N}}= \lbrace 1 \rbrace_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \to 1$. But somehow im not doing things right since the first sequence converges in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and the secobd converges to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The function is not defined on a neighbourhood of (0,0)

Comment: Do you mean for $f$ to be undefined on the axes (excepting the origin)? If not perhaps you mean for one of the "ands" to be an "or"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that we consider definition of continuity with respect to domain of given function $f$, which is all $\mathbb{R}^2$ without axes $Ox$ and $Oy$, but including origin $(0,0)$. Such definition and its extension even for non limit points we can find, for example, in John M.H. Olmsted, Advanced calculus, Prentice Hall,  1961, pages 186-187. Similar definition can be find, also, in Rudin W., Principles of mathematical analysis, McGraw Hill, 1976, pages 85-86.

So we have right to consider your example $(x_n,y_n)=\left(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}\right)$, because it belongs to function domain and converges to $(0,0)$. Corresponding sequence $f(x_n,y_n) = 1 \to 1 \ne 2 = f(0,0)$, so your example is correct and function is not continuous in origin.